# How to get week number and date of that week between two dates using MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I am using MySQL And I have two dates "From date" and "To date", and based on these date i want to get week number and dates of that week between "To" and "From" Dates.

I have tried the following mysql query.

```
SELECT count(*) as count,
       CONCAT(DATE_FORMAT(DATE_ADD(FROM_DAYS(TO_DAYS(FROM_UNIXTIME(`webform_submissions`.`submitted`)) -MOD(TO_DAYS(FROM_UNIXTIME(`webform_submissions`.`submitted`)) -1, 7)),INTERVAL -6 DAY),'%M %d'), ' - ' ,DATE_FORMAT(FROM_DAYS(TO_DAYS(FROM_UNIXTIME(`webform_submissions`.`submitted`)) -MOD(TO_DAYS(FROM_UNIXTIME(`webform_submissions`.`submitted`)) -1, 7)),'%M %d')) as date , 
       CONCAT(YEAR(FROM_UNIXTIME(`webform_submissions`.`submitted`)), '/', WEEK(FROM_UNIXTIME(`webform_submissions`.`submitted`))) as week
FROM `webform_submissions` 
where `webform_submissions`.`nid` = 121 
  AND DATE_FORMAT(FROM_UNIXTIME(`webform_submissions`.`submitted`), '%Y-%m-%d') between '2019-11-01' and '2019-12-03'
GROUP BY week 
ORDER BY `webform_submissions`.`submitted` ASC
```

The following result is display according to above query.

[image]

But it seems that it gives wrong result because week number 43 lies between 21-27 Oct and i want to get result between between '2019-11-01' and '2019-12-03'.

Expected output should be like the screenshot. Because From date "2019-11-01" lies between Oct 28- Nov 03 (Week 44). so records should be start from 44 week number.

[image]

Any Idea how to get correct number of week and dates?

Comment: Actually `week 43` lies between `21-27Oct` and your query result also showing the same. Why do you think it is wrong?

Comment: @ArunPalanisamy , Actually From date is Nov 1, so according to me first record comes under (28 Oct-03 Nov) as week 44, Because Nov 1 date lies between 44 week number

Comment: Are there values for every day?

Comment: @Nick, No some date have records and some dates does not have records between '2019-11-01' and '2019-12-03'.

Comment: What is your expected output?

Comment: @mkRabbani I have updated my question for expected output

Comment: What version of MySQL are you using?

Comment: @Nick I am using MySQL 5.6.45 version

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a somewhat easier to read version of your query (using nested subqueries since MySQL 5.6 doesn't support CTEs) and using [`DATE_FORMAT`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format) with the `%x/%v` format to generate the `week` to match your expected result (October 28 is the start of week 44). Note I've added a `MIN` into the generation of `date` so that the query will still work in MySQL 5.7 with SQL mode ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY.

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS count,
       CONCAT(DATE_FORMAT(MIN(startofweek), '%M %d'),
              ' - ',
              DATE_FORMAT(MIN(startofweek) + INTERVAL 6 DAY, '%M %d')) AS date,
       week
FROM (SELECT submitted - INTERVAL (dayofweek + 6) % 7 DAY AS startofweek,
             week
      FROM (SELECT nid, 
                   DATE(FROM_UNIXTIME(submitted)) AS submitted, 
                   DATE_FORMAT(FROM_UNIXTIME(submitted), '%w') AS dayofweek,
                   DATE_FORMAT(FROM_UNIXTIME(submitted), '%x/%v') AS week
            FROM webform_submissions
            WHERE nid = 121
              AND DATE(FROM_UNIXTIME(submitted)) BETWEEN '2019-11-01' AND '2019-12-03'
            ) AS dates
      ) AS ws
GROUP BY week
```

Output (for my sample data)

```
count   date                        week
3       October 28 - November 03    2019/44
4       November 04 - November 10   2019/45
```

[Demo on dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.6&fiddle=03198dd411b9a34c9c9a000f74c4a67b)

Answer (score 0):

Try to set the second parameter of WEEK() according to your expected result.

With the second parameter you can set the mode with wich you specify wether the week starts with sunday or monday, the week numbers starts with 0 or 1 and the rule defining the first week of the year.

See https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_week